# highcharts x-axis datetime value for one week coming wrong

Tags: highcharts

im using highcharts for reports the x-axis

> type:datetime and tickinterval:23 * 24 * 3600 * 1000

, i have another dropdown where in 
i can select the `CurrentYear,Past 30 days,Previous Month, Current Month,Past 7 days, Previous week , CurrentWeek report` the data comes
according to the selected value for CurrentYear the x-axis shows values jul'13,Aug'13,Sep'13...Mar'14 which is right since the tickinterval
is 1 month , but as soon as i select the one week report / current week report x-axis shows no point on it..i want atleast two point on 
the x-axis. i thought of using min and max for the same but can't use since the values of min and max will change according to the 
weeks.so is there any logic that will make my x-axis value constant to say 6 values or 5values of dates

Comment: so if a week has no data, you'd rather expand the range (say by going up your dropdown list in expanding range order) than show a 'no data in series' message? both are doable and require no highcharts specific coding. Or am I misinterpreting your problem?

Comment: yeh it is not highcharts specific coding.i will resolve this by taking some var and doing some logic on it..thks

Comment: np, comment here if you get stuck and i'll get more involved, else have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In general, instead of setting `tickInterval`, try to set `tickPixelInterval` - Highcharts will try to fix tick positions to fit pixel interval between them. It won't be exactly the same distance as you set in `tickPixelInterval` but something really close.

You have also another solution, when you set new data from dropdown you can also call: `chart.xAxis.update({ tickInterval: newvalue })` so for each dropdown value, you can set new interval, which workaround your issue.